# ReactJS - input validation doesn't validate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, validation

I am trying to make a validation for my form.

```
class Car extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            errors: {}
        }
     this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.errors) {
            this.setState({
                errors: nextProps.errors
            });
        }
    }

    handleNameChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const car = {
            name: this.state.name,
            ...
        }
        console.log(car);

        axios.post('/api/cars/create', car)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('response.data: ', response.data);

            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            });

    }

    render() {
        const { errors } = this.state;
        console.log('errors name: ', errors.name);
        ...
        return (
            <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: '50px'}}>
                <h2 style={{marginBottom: '40px'}}>Cars</h2>
                <form className="" onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <div className="form-group"> 
                                <label>Car Name</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Name"
                                    className={classnames('form-control form-control-sm', {
                                        'is-invalid': errors.name
                                    })}
                                    name="name"
                                    onChange={ this.handleNameChange }
                                    value={ this.state.name }
                                />
                                {errors.name && (<div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.name}</div>)}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        ...
                       );
    }
}
Car = {
    //registerUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ registerUser })(withRouter(Car))
```

Then, in **car.js**, I have the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const passport = require('passport');
const validateCarInput = require('../validation/car');

const Car = require('../models/Car');

router.post('/create', function(req, res) {
    console.log('in /create');
    console.log('req.body.name: '+req.body.name);

    const { errors, isValid } = validateCarInput(req.body);

    if(!isValid) {
        console.log('hello from validation');
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }
    ...
```

If I send the form with incorrect fields (empty `name`), I will get here the message from console `hello from validation`. That's good here.

And here's the `validations/car.js` file yet:

```
const Validator = require('validator');
const isEmpty = require('./is-empty');

module.exports = function validateCarInput(data) {
    let errors = {};
    console.log('x data.name: ', data.name);
    data.name = !isEmpty(data.name) ? data.name : '';

    if(Validator.isEmpty(data.name)) {
        errors.name = 'Name field is required';
        console.log('errors.name: ', errors.name);    
    }

    return {
        errors,
        isValid: isEmpty(errors)
    }
}
```

What is the problem - when I send out the form with empty `name` field - that means that the field is invalid - it cannot be empty - NodeJS is able to recognize this, but to the ReactJS component is not this information passed.

In the component, this line of code `console.log('errors name: ', errors.name);` always produce **undefined** for `errors.name` - and then, this information is never displayed on the website:

```
{errors.name && (<div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.name}</div>)}
```

Why ReactJS doesn't see the message from NodeJS and `errors.name` is always `undefined`?

Comment: When your server side validation fails, is this `console.log` executed? `.catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            })`

Comment: Hi @Dacreenny, yes - this is the output: `Error: Request failed with status code 400`

Comment: @user2932090 what does your server response looks like?

Comment: @xdhe the server response is `{ name: 'Name field is required' }` - it looks like I cannot add this object from the server to `setState`. When I try `this.setState({ errors: err.response.data })`, I get `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Comment: @user2932090 hmm I'm not really familiar with react as I am more into ionic. But in my experience, if the server send 400, my server respond is deep in property error of the respond. So in your case your server respond might in `respond.error.name`. To be sure can you `console.log` that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the axio documentation, error responses are structured with an optional `response` object. The response object if present, should contain your server-side json validation data, which is what you'd want to update your components state with:

This may be as simple as making the following changes:

```
axios.post('/api/cars/create', car)
.then(response => {
  console.log('response.data: ', response.data);

})
.catch((error) => { // Use arrow function to simplify setState access 

  // If error contains response data, attempt to extract server
  // side validation to update component state
  if(error.response) {
    this.setState({ errors : error.response.data })
  }
  else {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

For more information on axio error handling, see this https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Comment: Thank you @DacreDenny, this seems to be the right approach. However, when I try to update the `setState` like this, I get `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`. Looks like there's a problem with assigning an object to the state-object.

Comment: Hi there, you're welcome - did you change the `catch` function to be an arrow function? Like this? `.catch((error) => {`

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't! I overlooked it! Thanks, it works now ;) I am new to ReactJS/NodeJS, so I didn't fully understand the concept of arrow functions etc, so that's a bit confusing too.

Comment: Great to hear it's working now - yes, arrow functions are slightly different, they have some interesting properties, but are very useful for situations like this  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should put in the request this `.catch((error) => this.setState({error: {names: error}}))` but i think that the name should be like this `.catch(function(error) => this.setState({errors: {[name]: error}}))`but you have to know what is the name of the field that has the error

Comment: The think is that on the line you are mentioning, there's only this message in the `err`: `Error: Request failed with status code 400` - some generic one (not sure where it comes from). However, if I print out the error message form the validator, I get there this: `{ name: 'Name field is required' }` -- and this message is somehow not passed to React.